# Office Excel, irregular formulas with ranges?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I'm not sure how to implement a certain "formula" into Excel and I thought I'd ask you all for help.

I'm looking to implement a formula based on fixed values:
It's based on 2 numbers, A and B.

1. A is a range of numbers between 1-8, and B is 0.75.
2. A is a range between 9-13, and B is 0.90.
3. A is a range between 14-17, and B is 1.

As you can see, there is no correlation between the numbers; they are fixed values. I want my input numbers "A" and "B" to reflect this.

I'm planning on using a drop-down list/menu with values 1-20 in it, so whenever I choose a value between 9 and 13, the end result is always 0.90.

What do I have to do, in order to have these static values reflect each other from a drop-down list?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `VLOOKUP()` function.

Set your drop-down list to put value A into a cell (C2 in this example) and then use `VLOOKUP` to pick the corresponding value B from the lookup table (A2:B21 in this example).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a list in physical form, you can have it in the data validation.

Select where you want your drop down list, go to the *data* tab and select *data validation*. [image]

Select list, and either the range containing the values, or just the values directly.

Then, in the "B" cell, you can check the value of the list with two`=IF()` statements, like so:

```
=IF(A1<9,"0.75",IF(A1>13,"1","0.9"))
```

A1 being the location of the drop down list.

The value of B can also easily be fetched from a specific cell if you store the numbers of B somewhere. Just replace for example `"0.75"` with say `B2` or whatever suits your purpose.

Good luck!